# Serial Connection (Arduino --> Java)

Tags: javafx, arduino

this will be my first post and I will do my best to be clear and concise. I've checked some of the other posts on this forum but was unable to find a satisfactory answer.

My question pertains to the use of JavaFX and the jSSC(java simple serial connection) library. I've designed a very simple GUI application that will host four different charts. Two of the charts will display readings from temperature and solar sensors for the past hour, while the other two display that data over an extended period -- a 14-hour period. Eventually I would like to make that more flexible and set the application to "sleep" when the readings become roughly zero (night).

**How can I stream data to display this data in real time?**

After referencing several sources online and from "JavaFX 8 Intro. by Example", I've been able to construct most of the serial connection class. I'm having trouble processing the data readings, so that it can be displayed on the chart.

```
public class SerialComm  implements SerialPortEventListener {
Date time = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");

boolean connected;
StringBuilder sb;
private SerialPort serialPort;

final StringProperty line = new SimpleStringProperty("");

//Not sure this is necessary
private static final String [] PORT_NAMES = {
    "/dev/tty.usbmodem1411", // Mac OS X
    "COM11", // Windows
};
//Baud rate of communication transfer with serial device
public static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

//Create a connection with the serial device
public boolean connect() {
    String [] ports = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
    for (String port : ports) {
         System.out.print("Ports: " + port);
         serialPort = new SerialPort(port);
    }
    if (serialPort == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find device.");
        return false;
    }

    //Operation to perform is port is found
    try {
        // open serial port
        if(serialPort.openPort()) {
             System.out.println("Connected");
        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                serialPort.setEventsMask(SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);

        serialPort.addEventListener(event -> {
            if(event.isRXCHAR()) {
                try {
                    sb.append(serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue()));
                    String str = sb.toString();
                    if(str.endsWith("\r\n")) {
                            line.set(Long.toString(time.getTime()).concat(":").concat(
                                    str.substring(0, str.indexOf("\r\n"))));
                                                System.out.println("line" + line);

                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                    }
                } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SerialComm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);                    }
            }            
        });
    }                          
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ErrOr");
    e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }       
    return serialPort != null;
}

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
}

public StringProperty getLine() {
    return line;
}
```

}

Within the try block, I understand the port parameters, but the eventListener is where I am having difficulty. The significance of the stringbuilder is to append data the new data as it is read from the device. 
**How will I account for the two sensor readings? Would I do that by creating separate data rates to differentiate between the incoming data from each sensor??**

I hope that this is clear and that I've provided enough information but not too much. Thank you for any assistance.

-------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------

Since your reply Jose, I've started to make the additions to my code. Adding the listener within the JavaFX class, I'm running into some issues. I keep getting a NullPointerException, which I believe is the String[]data not being initialized by any data from the SerialCommunication class.

```
serialPort.addEventListener(event -> {
            if(event.isRXCHAR()) {
                try {
                    sb.append(serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue()));
                    String str = sb.toString();

                    if(str.endsWith("\r\n")) {
                            line.set(Long.toString(time.getTime()).concat(":").concat(
                                    str.substring(0, str.indexOf("\r\n"))));
                                                System.out.println("line" + line);
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                    }
                } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SerialComm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }            
        });
    }                          
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
```

I'm adding the time to the data being read. As Jose mentioned below, I've added tags to the data variables within the arduino code, I'm using: Serial.print("Solar:");  Serial.println(solarData);

Rough code of the JavaFx listener:

```
serialPort.getLine().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> {
        Platform.runLater(()-> {
            String [] data = t1.split(":");

            try {
                 //data[0] is the timestamp
                //data[1] will contain the label printed by arduino "Solar: data"

                switch (data[1]) {
                    case "Solar":
                        data[0].replace("Solar:" , "");
                        solarSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(data[0], data[1]));
                        break;
                    case "Temperature":
                        temperatureSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(data[0], data[1]));
                        break;
                }
```

**Is the reason this code has NullPointerException a result of the String [] data array being uninitialized?**

*Exception Error*

Ports: /dev/tty.usbmodem1411Connected
Exception in thread "EventThread /dev/tty.usbmodem1411" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SerialComm.lambda$connect$0(SerialComm.java:61)
    at SerialComm$$Lambda$1/1661773475.serialEvent(Unknown Source)
    at jssc.SerialPort$LinuxEventThread.run(SerialPort.java:1299)

Comment: Could you show the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Please, edit your post and add the full exception there.

Comment: The full stacktrace contains more information, and that would help tracking the error. Which line is 1299?

Comment: That is why I'm having trouble tracking down the error -- there is no line 1299. 

Also, I'm not sure how to expand on the exception thrown. I checked some other forums on how to do that...I will keep looking. sry
: /

Comment: SerialPort is from jssc library: `eventListener.serialEvent(new SerialPortEvent(portName, eventType, eventValue));`. SerialComm is your class? Line 61? You could add some `System.out.println()` to your `connect()` method to check in which line you have the NPE.

Comment: Yes, SerialComm is the name of the class. Jose, that is where the error was located. Foolish that I did not catch that one. TY. With that, this would mean that the problem is with the data transfer. Do you think it could be the way I've printed the data to serial in the arduino code? 
Serial.print("Solar: ); 
Serial.println(data);  
This is coming across as two different bytes of data instead of one..correct?
I will like your response to my question once I reach the required minmum reputation. ;)

Comment: First of all, you need to find the source of the problem. As I said before, you could log to console all the steps in SerialComm with `System.out.println()`, checking that everything goes as expected, until you find what is failing. I can't help you if you don't show the full exception or if you don't post all the code for SerialComm.

Comment: You need to initialize the StringBuilder!! `StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();`

Comment: Yes, I think it got removed when I was busy adjusting the code so many times trying to get something to work. The data is processing now -- albeit in a distorted fashion.

Comment: Is the RXTX library better for processing data? The ability to buffer the data does not exist with jSSC, and I think it is causing my data output to print random numbers with no significance. 
sb.append(serialPort.readString(event.getEventVale())); is printing the following:  
Solar-3.43
Solar-3.48
 48
 0
 53
 3
 43
It should look like the first 2 outputs.

Comment: I won't suggest going back to RXTX, it's no longer mantained. Even Arduino has moved to jSSC recently (1.5.6+). At what rate are you sending data from Arduino? Maybe you should add a small delay (100 ms). If you have weird values, log to console all the data you get, regardless the stringbuilder and see if that makes sense. Note that the new line characters can be sent at any time, so what really make sense is `line`, once you get them. Print it and see what it looks like.

Comment: I spent most of the night trying to work through this by altering the baud rates, modifying the delay within the arduino code, and changing the way stringbuilder appended the input. The string builder itself is very erratic after the first several lines -- initially it will print the data as expected, but then it contains random number (no string, which it should) that do not make sense. As you've mentioned, 'line', should be the focus, but its value does not contain the marker ("Solar") and the data is incorrect. The data changes after entering into the if statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75636/discussion-between-jose-pereda-and-wellington).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SerialPortEventListener` defined in the [jssc](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector) library allows listening for serial port events. One of those events is the `RXCHAR` event, that occurs when the Arduino board is sending some data and some bytes are on the input buffer.

`event.getEventValue()` returns an `int` with the byte count, and `serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue())` get the `String` format from those bytes.

Note that this method does not return a full line, so you need to listen to carriage return and line feed characters. Once you find `"\r\n"`, you can get the line, and reset the `StringBuilder` for the next one:

```
sb.append(serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue()));
String str=sb.toString();
if(str.endsWith("\r\n")){
    line.set(str.substring(0,str.indexOf("\r\n")));
    sb=new StringBuilder();
}
```

where `line` is an observable `String`:

```
final StringProperty line=new SimpleStringProperty("");
```

On the Arduino side, if you want to send values from different sensors at different rates, I suggest you define on the Arduino sketch some identification string for each sensor, and you print for each value the id of its sensor.

For instance, these will be the readings you will get with the serial event listener:

```
ID1,val1
ID1,val2
ID2,val3
ID1,val4
ID3,val5
...
```

Finally, on the JavaFX thread, define a listener to changes in `line` and process the `String` to get the sensor and the value. Something like this:

```
serial.getLine().addListener(
    (ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
    Platform.runLater(()->{
        String[] data=newValue.split("\\,");
        if(data[0].equals("ID1"){
            // add to chart from sensor 1, value data[1]; 
        } else if(data[0].equals("ID2"){
            // add to chart from sensor 2, value data[1]; 
        } else if(data[0].equals("ID3"){
            // add to chart from sensor 3, value data[1]; 
        }
    });        
});
```

Note you need to add `Platform.runLater()`, since the thread that gets the data from serial port and updates `line` is not on the JavaFX thread.

Comment: Jose, thank you very much for taking the time to explain the details of this code. It is almost verbatim from what the JavaFX book did, but you detailed some of the methods used much better for me. Would you mind explaining a little more about the addListener parameters? It is not clear to me what they represent.

Comment: I've edited my answer, replacing the arguments in the lambda expression with new ones with explicit parameters. Since this is a `ChangeListener()`, in `newValue` you have every new value set in `line`, so you have to process it accordingly to add the data to the chart depending on the sensor id.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, on the Arduino side, add a comma or something to separate the different values when you print and when you receive that string in Java simply split that string by commas.

```
String[] stringSeparate = str.split(",");
```